# How can I make mouse position values on x & y axis range between to values between -1 & 1?

Tags: jquery, math

How can I make the mouse position value instead of being irregular values to range between -1 & 1, effectively making the centre of the screen equal to 0, left on x -1, right on x 1, top -1, bottom 1?

```
var mouseX, mouseY;
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    console.log('x', mouseX)
    console.log('y',mouseY)
}).mouseover();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next formula:

```
x' = (2 * X - screenwidth) / screenwidth
y' = (2 * Y - screenheight) / screenheight
```

Comment: how would implement this into the code I provided above?

Comment: I don't know JQuery to say what element we should apply `width()` to. Perhaps `var width = $(window).width();` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var mouseX, mouseY;
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = (e.pageX * 2 - windowWidth) / windowWidth;
    mouseY = (e.pageY * 2 - windowHeight) / windowHeight;
    console.log('x', mouseX)
    console.log('y', mouseY)
}).mouseover();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers from MBo and Emma Kitching will produce floating values. As I understand it, you are looking exclusively for values of either -1 or 1. Therefore, it would help to just use a conditional statement.

```
var mouseX, mouseY;
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX < $(window).width() / 2 ? -1 : 1;
    mouseY = e.clientY < $(window).height() / 2 ? -1 : 1;
    console.log('result: (x, y) = (' + mouseX + ', ' + mouseY + ')');
}).mouseover();
```

Please note, that the code above uses the position within the browser window, irrespective of scrolling position. If you want to calculate your values with respect to the complete page and its size, use pageX/pageY and the page size instead.